# How to debug NoClassDefFoundError originating from a 3rd party jar?

Tags: java, debugging, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting NoClassDefFoundError while interacting with a 3rd party class which further does some native calls.

Wanted to know what is the best way to debug such an error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/somelib/SomeClass
    at MyTest.foo(MyTest.java:28)
    at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.somelib.SomeClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Well, it's looking for `com.somelib.SomeClass` - so do a search for that class, and provide the relevant jar file on the classpath. Check the documentation for the 3rd party library too - it may well give more details about dependencies.

Comment: If you really want help you'll update your post to show the ***unredacted*** stack trace showing the real class name that wasn't found, and tell us the library and version you're using.